# Across languages, what, if any, syntactic or semantic differences distinguish compound verbs from serial verb constructions?

Tags: syntax, semantics, verbs, compounds

Across languages, what semantic or syntactic differences distinguish serial verb constructions from compound verbs?  Let's disregard phonological differences for the purposes of this question.

Let's suppose we are talking about a nonce language in which the verb "ride" is either "sit-travel" (compound) or "sit # travel"  (serial verb construction).  Could these two constructions be synonymous in our nonce language?  Would they likely be?